# ember data one-to-one association returns undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have these two resources:

```
App.Users = DS.Model.extend({
    first_name: DS.attr('string'),
    last_name: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    userprofile: DS.belongsTo('App.Userprofiles', {embedded:true}),
    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('first_name') + ' ' + this.get('last_name');
    }.property('first_name', 'last_name'),
    didLoad: function() {
        console.log('Developer model loaded', this);
    }
});

App.Userprofiles = DS.Model.extend({
    company: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('App.Developers'),
    didLoad: function() {
        console.log('Developer Profile model loaded', this);
    }
})
```

These are my view and controller:

```
App.UserInfoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content: App.store.find(App.Users, 1),
}).create();

App.UserInfoView = Ember.View.extend({
    controller: App.UserInfoController,
    contentBinding: 'controller.content'
});
```

This a sample response for a user from my API

```
{
  "email": "foo@gmail.com",
  "first_name": "George",
  "id": "1",
  "last_name": "Eracleous",
  "resource_uri": "/api/v1/users/1/",
  "userprofile": {
    "company": "bar",
    "id": "1",
    "resource_uri": "/api/v1/userprofiles/1/",
    "user": "/api/v1/users/1/"
  }
}
```

The user object is loaded correctly but when I try to do get("userprofile") I get null. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load embedded related objects you have to configure the serializer used by the adapter, by calling its 'map' function. The only way I know to do this is by subclassing the serializer and add an 'init' function to it, where you make the necessary calls to map. For every embedded relationship of every model class you will have to do a call to 'map'. This applies to to-one and to-many relationships. Make sure to configure your adapter to use this serializer.
For an example see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538409/ember-data-fixtureadapter-with-embedded-hasmany/13627348#13627348) to a previous question.
You can also check out [this example](http://olmeca.nl/rae/emberdata1/) online.

As mentioned in the comment, instead of subclassing the serializer and calling its map() function in the initialiser you can directly call map() on the adapter class. As an example, here is an excerpt of my own code doing this.

```
WO.RESTAdapter.map(App.Category, {
 resourceTypes: {
  embedded: 'load'
}
});
WO.RESTAdapter.map(App.Resource, {
 resourceType: {
  embedded: 'load'
 }
});
WO.RESTAdapter.map(App.Reservation, {
 resource: {
  embedded: 'load'
 },
 user: {
  embedded: 'load'
 }
});
App.serializer = App.WOSerializer.create();
App.store = DS.Store.create({
 revision: 10,
 adapter: WO.RESTAdapter.create({
  namespace: "cgi-bin/WebObjects/Reserve.woa/ra",
  serializer: App.serializer
 }),
 serializer: App.serializer,
 adapterForType: function(type){
  return this.get('adapter');
 }
});
```

Comment: Hi. I tried it and it doesn't work. I am using version 10 btw

Comment: In version 10 the JSONSerializer was introduced, so now your serializer must subclass the JSONSerializer instead of the Serializer. I have updated the online example to user version 10, so check it out again.

Comment: Alternatively you can call map() on the RESTAdapter class (or your subclass thereof) the same way you would call map() on your Serializer subclass. I have tested this only with version 10. Note that you have to call map() on the Adapter (sub) class, not on an instance.

Comment: I tried the JSONSerializer thing but it still doesn't work. I am getting the feeling that probably something is wrong with my adapter. I haven't tried your suggestion for calling adapter's map(). How do I do that exactly?

Comment: I've added some example code to my original answer, showing how I'm calling map() on my RESTAdapter subclass.